# How stop sprouting turtles but continue the simulation

Tags: netlogo

I am implementing an SFM in NetLogo. I am having difficulties setting a fixed number of turtles in my world. I created my turtles with the sprout primitive (1 per patch) so I am not sure how can I set a fixed number for all turtles. I think using a slider is a good idea as I want to test different cases for e.g. 400, 500, 600 and so on turtles to analyze how long it will take them to evacuate.

Naturally, when I implemented *if count turtles > 100 [stop] create_adults* in the go procedure all the simulation stopped. I don't want the simulation to stop. I want only to stop creating turtles, so the turtles already in the world can continue moving.

Here is my go procedure:

```
to go
if ticks = 0 [reset-timer]
if random 100 > 30                                                                        
[repeat random 3  [create_adults]]
    tick
if count turtles > 400 [stop] create_adults
```

This is how I am creating my turtles:

```
 to create_adults
  let p one-of patches with [(pycor >= 1 and pycor <= 11 and pxcor = 3) and pcolor = violet + 2]      ; this is the beginning of my world                      
          ask p [ if not any? turtles-here
            [sprout-adults 1
               [ set shape "circle"
                 set color magenta
                 set heading 90
                 set goal one-of patches with [(pycor >= 1 and pycor <= 11 and pxcor = max-pxcor) and pcolor = brown + 2]
                 set vi (list (0.66) 0)
                 set r 0.35 
                 set size (0.7)
                 set mass 74.15
]
]
]
                             
      if count turtles > 400 [ask p [stop]] ; not working either
stop-creating-turtles
```

I also tried creating a new variable

```
        to stop-creating_turtles
              if count turtles > 400 [stop create_adults]
        end
```

Then I added in the *to create_adults* procedure but is not working as I think I have a misunderstanding in the approach.

I don't have globals in my model and

```
my turtles-own [
goal
vi
r
size
mass]
```

My simplified *to move* procedure

```
to move
  ask turtles
 [  fd module vi / fps
]
```

I think I am confused about how to approach this issue because I don't know how to make a relation between the *to create_adults* procedure and the count turtles report.

I appreciate in advance for your thoughts. I hope this is understandable as this is my first post =)!

I implemented Matteo's long suggestion but my turtles are still created after reaching the threshold.

The simplified version of the edited code is as follows:

```
globals [turtles-reached-threshold?]

breed [adults adult]

turtles-own [
              goal
               ]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set-environment
  set turtles-reached-threshold? FALSE
end

to set-environment
  ;for walls in lime color
  ask patches with [(pxcor >= min-pxcor and pxcor <= max-pxcor and pycor = 12)] [set pcolor lime + 1 ]
  ask patches with [(pxcor >= min-pxcor and pxcor <= max-pxcor and pycor = min-pycor)] [set pcolor lime + 1 ]

  ;to create-agents
  ask patches with [pycor >= 1 and pycor <= 11 and pxcor = -16] [set pcolor violet + 2]

 ;to kill-agents
 ask patches with [pycor > 0 and pycor <= 11 and pxcor = max-pxcor] [set pcolor brown + 2] 
end

to go
  if ticks = 0 [reset-timer]
if count turtles > 0 [move]
  if (random 100 > 30) [
    repeat random 5 [create_adults]
  ]
  if (count turtles < 21) AND (turtles-reached-threshold?) [
    create_adults
    if (not turtles-reached-threshold?) AND (count turtles > 20) [
      set turtles-reached-threshold? TRUE
    ]
  ]
ask turtles [if pcolor = brown + 2 [die]] 
  tick
end

 to create_adults
  let p one-of patches with [(pycor >= 1 and pycor <= 11 and pxcor = -16) and pcolor = violet + 2]      ; this is the beginning of my world                      
          ask p [ if not any? turtles-here
            [sprout-adults 1
               [ set shape "circle"
                 set color magenta
                 set heading 90
                 set goal one-of patches with [(pycor >= 1 and pycor <= 11 and pxcor = max-pxcor) and pcolor = brown + 2]
                 
]
]
]
end

to move
  ask turtles
 [
    fd 1
 ]
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

In your `go` procedure, just use `if (count turtles < 401) [create_adults]` - so you are using your condition to create turtles and not to stop the procedure.

### Longer answer

The approach above is the simplest. Your approach was more of an [`ifelse`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse) type because you were making explicit both your intention to create turtles (with `create_turtles`) and your intention not to do it (with `stop`). However the use of `stop` is excessive in this case, because what you meant was just "*Don't create the turtles / don't do anything*" and not "*Exit this procedure*".

In other words, with `ifelse` it would have had to be something like

```
ifelse (count turtles > 400)
  []
  [create_turtles]
```

But that empty command block suggests us that using a simple `if` (but the other way around, as I showed at the beginning of the answer) is just enough.

### Something to note

The approach above results in the fact that, at every `go` iteration, turtles will be created if there are less than 401 of them. This will surely happen at the beginning of the simulation, and that is fine. However, *if your model includes turtles dying*, this means that turtles would be created again if their number **falls below 401**. This is something that you may or may not want. If you don't want it to happen, a possible solution would be to create a global variable to control for this. For example, you could have something like

```
globals [
  turtles-reached-threshold?
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set turtles-reached-threshold? FALSE
end

to go
  if ticks = 0 [reset-timer]

  if (random 100 > 30) [
    repeat random 3 [create_adults]
  ]

  if (count turtles < 401) AND (turtles-reached-threshold?) [
    create_adults
    if (not turtles-reached-threshold?) AND (count turtles > 400) [
      set turtles-reached-threshold? TRUE
    ]
  ]

  tick
end
```

Comment: Dear Matteo thank you so much for your answer. Indeed you kinda guess my purpose because I did not mention I have turtles dying and either mentioned the "if count turtles > 0 [move]" line inside the "go" procedure. I implemented your long answer but is not working, I wonder if you may have a look at the edited code to help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you so much again!